# How to write a test class for covering Bundle product?

Tags: code-coverage, cpq, steelbrick

I am trying to cover a class in which I have below condition which contains one variable called SBQQ__Bundle__c available on QuoteLine Object of steel brick CPQ.
I have tried to investigate regarding SBQQ__Bundle__c and found that 
"SBQQ__Bundle__c Checkbox Indicates whether this line item represents a package; meaning, it includes other line items in this quote." so to cover this check box I should have one product associated with other. but I am not sure how to associate one product with other. Can anyone please help me here as I am new to Steel Brick CPQ.

Main Class Condition:

```
if(quoteLineObject.SBQQ__Bundle__c)
{----Logic-------}
```

Test Class logic to cover above condition:

```
Product2 prodObjSample = new Product2();
        prodObjSample.Name = 'TestProduct';
        prodObjSample.ProductCode = 'xyz-1555';
        prodObjSample.IsActive = true;
        prodObjSample.Tax_Category__c = 'Test Category';
        insert prodObjSample;
```

but i am not sure which field will help me to associate the above product with another product to make the SBQQ__Bundle__c Checkbox to true.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically controlled by a product having a product option associated with it in CPQ.

However, since this is managed by steelbirkc, you'd need to call the API to test the native logic in CPQ so, to test this, you'll probably want to create the quote and quote line manually in your test class.